# Navigating From One local Host to another in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation

How can i navigate from one localHost:3000 to localHost:3001 in react Js
currently my auth is running in localHost:3000 and i want to navigate it to localHost:3001 when login successful

my current implementation is like
`{agency && <Navigate to={"http://localhost:3001/"} replace />}`

but it navigate me to `http://localhost:3000/Login/localhost:3001/`

but i want **http://localhost:3001**

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-router-dom` only handles internal navigation actions, i.e. it can only link to and route within the React application. `"http://localhost:3001/"` is interpreted as an internal path and is appended to the current path.

If you need to navigate to an external (to the app) URL you should use raw anchor (`<a />`) tags or issue an imperative redirect via the `window.location` object.

Create a new navigation component to handle issuing the side-effect of external redirect in an `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
const NavigateExternal = ({ to }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.location.href = to;
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

...

```
{agency && <NavigateExternal to="http://localhost:3001/" />}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3001/'
```

Or using good practices

```
const redirectToExternalResource = url => window.location.href = URL

redirectToExternalResource('http://localhost:3001/')
```